# At what voltage per cell should I store a LiPo?

Tags: lipo-batteries, batteries, battery-safety, storage

Some sources say you should store your batteries at [3.85V](https://www.instructables.com/id/Lithium-Polymer-Etiquette/) per cell, other says it should be 3.7V.

My charger (ISDT Q6 Lite) on the "Storage" mode has a thumbs-up mark at 3.7V, probably indicating that it's the best voltage, at the same time when I ordered some CNHL LiPos, they came charged to ≈3.85V per cell.

Are there any papers/experiments about storage voltage or maybe this difference is neglectable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question seems to be quite the debate in many places. However, the general consensus falls between 3.7 and 3.85v per cell. You can find a similar inquiry here: [Storing at 3.7 or 3.85v](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2174990-Storing-at-3-7-or-3-85-v-s-Which-Is-Best) and here: [LiPo storage voltage](https://www.helifreak.com/showthread.php?t=68745)

It seems that generally, the difference between storage charging to 3.7v, 3.8v, or 3.85v is negligible for most people. However, I would recommend 3.7-3.8v per cell. I store my LiPos at 3.8v per cell and all of my year-old LiPos perform almost like they are brand new.

The exact voltage you storage charge LiPos is important, but it is even more important that you just take good care of them and do storage charge them. It's better to storage charge LiPos to a close enough voltage than to not storage charge them at all.

Here is a pretty useful guide to LiPo batteries: [Guide to understanding LiPo batteries](https://rogershobbycenter.com/lipoguide/)